# Groovy list files/directory in an http connection

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a Java library to list all files/directory in a remote http URL:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://howto.unixdev.net").get();
        for (Element file : doc.select("td.right td a")) {
            System.out.println(file.attr("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd need to do the equivalent thing with a Groovy script (as part of a Jenkins job)  but I couldn't find any example of it, except for file system listing. Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you face any specific issue?

Comment: are you using jenkins pipeline?